# SQL Server needed in client pc to work software created in VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have created one software with the use of SQL Server 2005. and already created setup file. It is working when i install it in my computer. but when i tried it to install on other computer which does not have sql server then it is not working because it did not find sql server.

Please help me. How can i run any software on client pc without installing sql server to their pc?

Or

Give me code through that setup can install sql server to the client or any pc if sql server is not installed on that machine.

Comment: What kind of application is it? Judging by the `asp.net` tag it's a web application? Does your installer setup a website in IIS?

Comment: How did you manage to develop an application and not know that SQL Server was required!

Comment: Sql Server is a very poor choice as the data store for a desktop app where you will keep the data on the local machine. Instead, you should be looking for an _in-process_ database engine, such as sqlite, Sql Server _Compact_ Edition, or even Access.

Comment: Also, does this question have anything to do with asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you developed a web application with SQL Server and created a setup file, you  really need to install SQL Server to the client PC for your application to work and install completely.

Installing your software in your computer (I assume it's your development machine) worked since you had SQL Server already in place.